# Is there any way to do a mathematical addition between methods?

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I want to know if there is any way to do a mathematical addition between methods? The code is as below.

From Main: (I need to the calculation but I can not do calculation between methods)

```
Ball.setPositionY = Ball.setPositionY + Ball.setSpeedY;
```

From a Class:

```
public class Ball
    {
    public int speedX { get; set; }
    public int speedY { get; set; }
    public int positionX { get; set; }
    public int positionY { get; set; }

    public Ball(int speedX, int speedY, int positionX, int positionY)
    {
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }

    public void setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
    {
        speedX = newSpeedX;
    }

    public void setSpeedY(int newSpeedY)
    {
        speedY = newSpeedY;
    }

    public void setPositionX(int newPositionX)
    {
        positionX = newPositionX;
    }

    public void setPositionY(int newPositionY)
    {
        positionY = newPositionY;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Why have `setSpeedX`, etc. when you already have property setters? I think what you want to say is `Ball.positionY = Ball.positionY + Ball.speedY`, which works in your current code.

Comment: Yeah, position and speed are better as properties and in your code there some redundancy that should be avoided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about letting the set method also return the value that was set or add a get method that gives you that same value. But...since you want that, why don't you just use the public properties on the object?

So, your method(s) can look like

```
public int setPositionX(int newPositionX)
{
    positionX = newPositionX;
    return newPositionX;
}
```

But, since you are creating your own getters and setters now and you already have them. Use the public properties and all should be fine.

Comment: Hi @Baszz, I do not understand. Is it possible for you to show me the example?

Comment: The error is Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'method group'.

Comment: @Baszz your `void` should be `int`or do i miss something?

Comment: @ElaineHarden It's quite simple. if both methods you call return an int, the + operator should work fine. So one of those methods probably isn't doing that.

Comment: @Baszz Do you have any idea how can I do it?

Comment: @Baszz One of the method is not working now. How can I do about it?

Comment: You need to be more specific. Which method is not working and that is not working exactly?

Comment: @Baszz Sorry about it. Ball.setPositionY = Ball.positionY + Ball.setSpeedY; The Ball.positionY is not working. The error is The object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.

Comment: setPositionY is a function, not a property. So assigning to it is not possible.  Ball.setPositionY(Ball.positionY + Ball.setSpeed) should work fine.

Comment: Then Ball is probably not an instance of the class Ball. You might want to do a var ball = new Ball() first and use the (lowercased) ball instance to call the method on.

Answer (score 7):

This is how you should do it:

```
public class Ball
{
    public int SpeedX { get; set; }
    public int SpeedY { get; set; }
    public int PositionX { get; set; }
    public int PositionY { get; set; }

    public Ball(int speedX, int speedY, int positionX, int positionY)
    {
        this.SpeedX = speedX;
        this.SpeedY = speedY;
        this.PositionX = positionX;
        this.PositionY = positionY;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ball ball1 = new Ball(1,1,1,1);
        Ball ball2 = new Ball(2,2,2,2);
        Ball ball3 = new Ball(3,3,3,3);
        ball3.SpeedX = ball1.SpeedX + ball2.SpeedX;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your properties are public, wouldn't it make sense to have a default constructor (or at least as an option)?

Answer (score 0):

After assigning the value, you just return the value. It will solve your problem. If you want to use methods.

For eg.

```
public int setSpeedX(int newSpeedX)
{
  speedX = newSpeedX;
  return speedX;
}
```

Comment: Be careful to document the function's return values, because it's only one of the two most common behaviors (the other being returning the previous value).

Answer (score 0):

That's what properties are for; you should use the properties for that.

If you mean an addition in the functional programming sense, I can make no sense of your example.

Answer (score 0):

Since all your methods have `void` return type there's no way to "add" them.
If you want to do that, change return type of your methods to `int`.

**Edit**

You can "add" methods that have `int` return type, but the result can't be a method.

Sample:

```
public int setPositionY(int newPositionY)
{
    positionY = newPositionY;
    return positionY;
}

public int setSpeedY(int newSpeedY)
{
    speedY = newSpeedY;
    return speedY;
}

positionY = setPositionY(/*new position*/) + setSpeedY(/*new speed*/);
```

Comment: Hi @Spaceman, it still prompts the same error that Operator '+' cannot be applied.

Comment: See my edit. Anyway, as other suggested, the correct way is to use Properties.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods must return value in order to add them,but public properties do what you want.
Ball.positionY =Ball.positionY + Ball.SpeedY;

Answer (score 0):

try the below code...

```
namespace Foo
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Ball b = new Ball(1,2,3,4);

        //b.setPositionY() = b.setSpeedY() + b.setSpeedY();
       b.setPositionY(b.setSpeedX() + b.setSpeedY());            

    }
}

public class Ball
{
    public int speedX { get; set; }
    public int speedY { get; set; }
    public int positionX { get; set; }
    public int positionY { get; set; }

    public Ball(int speedX, int speedY, int positionX, int positionY)
    {
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
        this.positionX = positionX;
        this.positionY = positionY;
    }

    public int setSpeedX()
    {
        //speedX = newSpeedX;
        return 10;
    }

    public int setSpeedY()
    {
        //speedY = newSpeedY;
        return 20;
    }

    public int setPositionX()
    {
        //positionX = newPositionX;
        return 1;
    }

    public void setPositionY(int newPositionY)
    {
        positionY = newPositionY;

    }
}
```